# JavaScript filtering array full of objects

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with some basic javascript. I want this function to return an array of all objects within the given array that have the name "Ray" assigned to name. I can't get the push part to work.

```js
  const people = [{name: "Jack", age: 30}, {name: "Ray", age: 32}, {name: "Anna", age: 28}]; 
  
function findRay(arr) {
  let response = []; 
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].name === "Ray") {
      response.push(arr[i]); 
    }
  }
  return response;
}
  
console.log(findRay(people));
```

Comment: Works fine for me, it returns an array with the Ray object.

Comment: Concur that it works.  What browser are you using?  Try changing const people = [......] to var people = [......]

Comment: I'm on Chrome. Also tried in Repl.it. This code does not work.

Comment: Works fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/nm0566y2/1/ .......

Comment: Well, it does: https://repl.it/JwCl Maybe explain what do you mean with "does not work"?

Comment: I forgot to add console.log to my local code... silly mistake. Thank you for pointing out that this version worked.

Answer (score 2):

While not exactly what you were looking for, this is a good use case for `filter()`. So you could do something like `const findRay = arr => arr.filter(person => person.name === "Ray")`.